# Display contains for integer array using ternary operator in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I just want to check that zip codes that are entered by user in an array or not but I am getting error; please help with that.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace checkzips
{
      class Program
      {  
           public static object f;

           public static void Main(string[] args)
           {       
               // create an integer array for package delivery service
               int[] zipcodes = { 07847, 07848, 07866, 07801, 07808, 07898, 07836,    07854, 07823, 07845 };

               // display original values of array
               Console.WriteLine("All zip codes to which the company delivers packages:");

               foreach (var elements in zipcodes)
                   Console.WriteLine("{0}", elements);

               // prompt a user to enter a zip code
               Console.WriteLine("Enter a zipcode:");
               Console.ReadLine();

               // search the array using foreach loop 
               Console.WriteLine("", f.zipcodes.Contains(Console.ReadLine()) ? string.Empty : "not");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error in last `Console.WriteLine` statement:

> Error CS1929 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and
>   the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains(IQueryable, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'  checkzips
>   H:\checkzips\checkzips\Program.cs 23

Comment: When you cram several logical operations into one line of code, it is difficult to understand and debug....as you are finding out.

Comment: Don't you want to store the first Console.ReadLine() to a variable and use that in the next line?  Or omit that first readline and just use the second one?

Comment: its just like ternary operator in last line to check whether zipcodes is in that array or not but i m getting error

Comment: i tried to use variable but its the same thing @devlincarnate

Comment: A zip code shouldn't be treated as a number, because it is perfectly legal for a zip code to start with 0. This will be stripped in the numeric conversion.

Comment: why do you call `zipcodes` on `f` (in  `f.zipcodes.Contains(...)`) ?

Comment: yup i noticed that @spender

Answer (score 3):

As-posted your code does not compile since `f` is declared as an `object` and does not have a `zipcodes` property.  However, since it seems to recognize `f.zipcodes` an `int[]` for some reason you obviously have different code than what is shown and that's causing the error you indicate.

The problem is that `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string` and you cannot use `Contains` on a collection of integers by passing it a string value.

Since you're dealing with ZIP codes it would be more appropriate to store them as strings rather than integers since they can start with `0` and contain non-numeric characters (`-`).  I suspect you want:

```
  string[] zipcodes = { "07847", "07848", "07866", "07801", "07808", "07898", "07836","07854", "07823", "07845" };
  ...
  string zip = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine("",f.zipcodes.Contains(zip) ? string.Empty : "not");
```

Note that it's better practice to put `Console.ReadLine` outside ofthe `WriteLine` - it allows you to validate input, improves debugging ability, etc.

Also note that you have a stray `Console.ReadLine()` that you are not capturing the input of.  I suspect you'd catch that during debugging but thought I'd point it out.

Comment: A zip code is a 5 numeric character string with (potentially) leading zeros. You might want to take this into account in your answer.

Comment: @spender.  Good suggestion.  Done.

Comment: @w.b. It will bind to the Linq `Contains` method which works fine on arrays.